# Why is my Skype menu bar icon black?

Tags: macos, skype

I noticed one day that the Skype icon in my Mac OS X menu bar was black.

[image: screenshot]

Skype notes when I'm online, but what specifically does the black color indicate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The icon becoming black and white is a change introduced in the latest revision (at least in 5.7).

It's basically just Skype becoming more dedicated to the OS X user interface, which doesn't encourage colorful menu bar items. Actually, people have often complained about the colored menu bar items before. I presume Skype finally addressed these concerns.

<sub>And in fact, Dropbox for example allows you to change the icon to black and white in its Preferences.</sub>

You can get the colors back by installing v5.6 from http://mac.oldapps.com/skype.php

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that. How did you find out? :D

Comment: I just cross-checked with older Skype installations. Also, the Skype forums were full of "Make the darn menu bar item black!" messages , so I figured they'd eventually changed it ;)